# XAML UserControl datatrigger

Tags: xaml

I have a UserControl in XAML with a couple of buttons....

When the "VideoEnable" property in my C# code change to true I want to change the color of a button.

The following code compiles but crashes and I can't find a right solution

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VideoEnable}" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Green" TargetName="VideoButton" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Blue" TargetName="videoGrid" />
    </DataTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

---

Now i have tried with the following code, it does not crash but the background does not change :s

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Videos}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

    public string Videos
    {
        get { return m_videos; }

        set
        {
            m_videos = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Videos");
        }
    }
```

---

Ok, I found the problem...

This is my button

```
        <Button DataContext="{Binding LensesBtn}" Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Height="40" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
            <Button.Background>#dbebf9</Button.Background>
            <Button.BorderBrush>PowderBlue</Button.BorderBrush>
            <Button.BorderThickness>4</Button.BorderThickness>
            Lenses
        </Button>
```

When I delete the DataContext, Style and Background properties it all works....

But i really need this properties

any tips?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: The application just crash. I think that i use the dataTrigger in a wrong way:s?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Videos" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

this is the example you need if your code is valid.
you can also add a converter in order to check the background and other properties.